# Cargo failing to load manifest for workspace member

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Any cargo command that relates to a project fails due to cargo either:

1. trying to find a Cargo.toml in the parent directory (the parent directory is not a rust project, and is just my projects folder)
2. trying to find a Cargo.toml in another one of my project folders for some reason (is not a rust project either)

## Error:

```
error: failed to load manifest for workspace member `/home/celestial/Documents/projects/graphs`

Caused by:
  failed to read `/home/celestial/Documents/projects/graphs/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

## Cause:

I was making a simple script to create a boilerplate project for me in rust (code below)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -n "$1" ]; then
    echo "use $(basename "$0") <project-name> instead!"
    exit
fi

BASE="$(eval echo ~)/Documents/projects"
NEW_PROJECT="$BASE/$1"

mkdir -p $NEW_PROJECT
cd $NEW_PROJECT
cargo init

xdg-open $NEW_PROJECT

if which bacon; then
    echo "bacon found! running..."
    (cd $NEW_PROJECT && bacon)
fi
```

and after running it a few times while debugging it, this error started occurring

## Attempted Solutions:

1. reinstalling rust via rustup
2. adding `[source.crates-io] registry = "https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"` into my ~/.cargo/config (saw in another so answer)
3. running cargo init in the folders its trying to find (it just complains about different folders if i fix the folders it complains about)
4. removing the project entirely and creating a new rust project (this happens on every rust project i have)
5. checking permissions of the folders (they're all 777)
6. resetting workspace (?) couldn't figure out how workspaces work

Comment: I'm guessing that there is a `/home/celestial/Documents/projects/Cargo.toml` with something like `[workspace] members = ["*"]`. Remove this file.

Comment: If that's not it, check all parent dirs for `Cargo.toml`, `.cargo/config`, or `.cargo/config.toml`.

Comment: turns out there was a Cargo.toml in my ~ folder for some reason, thought i checked that a few times, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

turns out there was a Cargo.toml in my ~ folder, so just check if there are any Cargo.tomls in any parent directory!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).